# Confusing behavior comparing "" to String.Empty and Null Coalesce operator (??)

Tags: c#, string, null-coalescing-operator

[image]

The behavior shown here is very perplexing to me. If `""` is equal to `String.Empty`, and null coalesce (`??`) works on `"" ?? "It works"` then why doesn't `test ?? "It works"` or `String.Empty ?? "It works"` act accordingly?

**Note:** *`Console.WriteLine("It works",String.Empty ?? "It works");` throws the exact same `AssertFailedException`*

** **UPDATE #1** **

The current answers are not agreeing with the results. As seen in these examples...

- `"" == String.Empty` is `true`
- `null == ""` is `true`
- `null == String.Empty` is `false`

These do not agree with each other. It's a case of A = B, B = C, but A != C

[image]

** **UPDATE #2** **

Answering @Willem Van Onsem's question about using `Console.WriteLine("" == null);`

[image]
[image]

This would be the expected results. So, it seems this is possibly a problem specific to `Assert.AreEqual(...,...)`

** **UPDATE #3** **

Please be aware that I'm perfectly aware of, and was before posting this question, how the `??` works and that `"" == null` is `false`. I know that it is only supposed to check equality to `null`. I know that `x ?? y` is equivalent to `x != null ? x : y`. This has been repeated entirely too much in the answers and comments to the point it's becoming insulting. Think about this, if I didn't know how the operator is *supposed* to work and thought anything past the first `Assert` was supposed to pass, then why would I be confused and post the question?

Comment: `??` checks for `null`...

Comment: and empty string is not `null`

Comment: The second one shouldn't work, are you sure vs isn't pointing to the wrong line of code?

Comment: The third one shouldn't work either.

Comment: Only the first should pass. It might be an issue with the IDE

Comment: Downvoters, if your IDE indicated that the 2nd case passed, wouldn't you be confused as well?

Comment: When I run your code it fails on `Assert.AreEqual("It works", "" ?? "It works");` as expected.

Comment: @Novaterata: I think VS got stuck somewhere (I've heard this sometimes happens).

Comment: *So... once again, when using the ?? operator. "" == null otherwise we should have seen Results in foo on the Console Output, right?*. No. Remember, ?? checks for null. Since "" is not null, it outputs `"Results in " + ""`...

Comment: `"" == null` is always false.

Comment: @juharr, If it fails... Then your test is agreeing with my screenshots, despite the fact everyone agrees `"" == null` is `false`. What compiler did you try this in?

Comment: @DanielA.White, Yes... I know... I don't think you've understood the purpose of my question. Please look at the screenshots again. Everyone here including me agree's that `"" == null` is `false`, but that is not the behavior being displayed in my screenshots. That is the purpose of the question. If thought `"" == null` was `true`. Then why would I be confused about this and post the question? It would have been doing what I expected, right?

Comment: @DrewChapin It's not the compiler, it's a bug with the debugger and the IDE misaligning the exception

Comment: @DrewChapin try it again but with different strings for each case other than "it works"

Comment: Why is Update 1 saying `null == ""` is true, while Update 2 is showing that it isn't true?

Comment: Your screen shot shows that it passed that one and failed on the next one, that's not what happened when I ran your code.  Try a rebuild and run the tests again is all I can suggest.  I'm running VS 2015 Update 3.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, In #1, I'm showing that the results of those tests are treating `null == ""` as `true`. Which WE all know it's not. In #2 I'm saying it works correctly as WE all would expect that `null == ""` should be `false`. This debating over my understanding of the equality between an `""` and `null`, and my understanding of how the `??` operator is **supposed** to work is getting really annoying, and insulting. No one is actually answering the question. Everyone just seems to think I'm stupid, and are ignoring that VS is disagreeing with the `"" == null` is `false`  in my test method.

Comment: Please include the version of Visual Studio you are running, The version of .NET you are using. Debug vs Release. Anything like that

Comment: `??` is a red herring. Please use unique strings for each test case so you can see which line actually failed

Comment: @Novaterata, I'm so done with everyone who has responded to this question. I know which line it's failing on. VS highlights it for me. I didn't Photoshop the screenshot. I know how `??` is supposed to work, I know `"" == null` is *supposed* to be `false`. Please quit assuming I'm an idiot. If you don't know why VS is breaking the rules, then don't participate.

Comment: I don't see how my advice assumes you are an idiot. I'm literally defending you and offering an explanation.

Comment: @Novaterata, I apologize. If you look around how many people have only focused one my understand of `"" == null` and how the `??` operator works. You'll see why I'm getting irate.

Comment: I agree, I just really want to know what happens when you do what i suggest

Answer (score 4):

The [**null-coalescing operator `??`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) checks for `null`. `x ?? y` is short for:

```
x == null ? y : x
```

So if you have an empty string, then the `x == null` fails (meaning it is `false`), and thus `"" ?? "It works"` results in `""`, as we can see in the `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> "" ?? "It works"
""
csharp> "" == null
false
```

Or as specified in the documentation:

> The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the **left-hand operand if the operand is not `null`**; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

**EDIT**: about update #1:

When I run the queries on the `csharp` interactive shell (this is the *Mono C# shell*):

```
csharp> "" == String.Empty
true                                    
csharp> null == ""                      
false                                   
csharp> null == String.Empty            
false
```

Something seems to be messed up with the IDE.

Comment: The code does not agree with you on *`"" ?? "It works"` results in `""`* In the example it results in `"It works`". So VS is treating `"" == null` as `true`

Comment: @DrewChapin: that is impossible: `"" == null` is false. What happens if you print `Console.WriteLine("" == null)` and `Console.WriteLine("" ?? "foo")`?

Comment: @DrewChapin: perhaps you should restart VS. Perhaps you accidently continued a program that already crashed somewhere.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE #2** on my question for the answer to your question.

Comment: @DrewChapin: well, it confirms that `"" == null` is not true (*fails* in the answer). So the answer is correct...

Comment: I will agree with you that `"" == null` is `false`. That much I expected. What I'm pointing out here is that null coalesce (`??`) treats `"" == null` as `true`. To answer your other question. I cleaned the solution, closed VS, deleted the `bin` and `obj` directories, re-opened VS, and it still shows the same results as all of my earlier tests.

Comment: @DrewChapin: no, the last line is an empty line, so that means that the `"" ?? "foo"` resulted in the empyt string, again as expected. The last three test written in the inital answer should all fail.

Comment: Guys, I'm aware that `"" == null` should be `false`. The issue here that I'm asking is why this inconsistent behavior occurring when I use the `??` operator?

Comment: @DrewChapin: It does not. It has been tested by a lot of people in the comment section of this question. Furthermore it perfectly explains why `"" ?? "foo"` prints `""`.

Comment: you are correct about the `Console.WriteLine` case. My mistake. However, this just indicates that the issue has something to do with `Assert.AreEqual(...,...)`

Comment: Your statements seem conflicting to me. You originally stated the exact same thing I said (`"" == null` is `false`). Now you are saying it's not, but then later in your comment you revert to saying it is `true`. I don't understand. I think everyone (including me) are responding too quickly and not taking time to fully read and understand the comments

Comment: @DrewChapin: `x ?? y` is *equvalent* to `x == null ? y : x` So that means that `"" ?? "foo"` is equivalent to `"" == null ? "foo" : ""`. So it checks if `"" == null` which is `false`, so it returns `""` (and ignores the `"foo"`). (mind that it is `? y : x`, not `? x : y`...

Comment: yes I'm perfectly aware of how it's supposed to work. I know that `??` is only supposed to check for `null`. I know that `"" ?? "It works"` is equivalent to `"" == null ? "It works" : ""`. I knew this before I posted the question. I really wish you guys would stop repeating this. It's becoming insulting. As I've shown in my screenshots. VS is not agreeing with what should and should not be. That is the point of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Null coalesce operator understands `null`, but has no idea about an empty string, which, obviously, different from `null`.

If you would like to treat an empty string and a `null` in the same way, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
Assert.AreEqual("It works", !String.IsNullOrEmpty(test) ? test : "It works")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that there is an IDE bug in which the Debug Exception alert box is pointing to the wrong line. These things happen. Stacktraces can lie, code can end up optimized so that the ordering is different. Who knows. In order to verify:

```
var test = String.Empty;

Assert.AreEqual("", String.Empty);
Assert.AreEqual("Case 1", "" ?? "Case 1");
Assert.AreEqual("Case 2", test ?? "Case 2");
Assert.AreEqual("Case 3", String.Empty ?? "Case 3");
```

Here is a link to someone reporting the issue to Microsoft with both confirmation by a 2nd person and a video that shows it happening:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641947/exception-assistant-highlights-incorrect-line-of-code